# How to reset stereo_image_proc?

Tags: stere-image-proc, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the [stereo parameter tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters) when `stereo_image_proc` suddenly crashed and would not restart. When I try to restart it, I get the error:

```
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (SADWindowSize must be odd, be within 5..255 and be not larger than image width or height) in findStereoCorrespondenceBM, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp, line 805
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp:805: error: (-211) SADWindowSize must be odd, be within 5..255 and be not larger than image width or height in function findStereoCorrespondenceBM
```

Clearly, I've set the SADWindowSize parameter to a bad value, but I have no idea how to unset it. The only way to change it is through `rqt_reconfigure` while `stereo_image_proc` is running, but `stereo_image_proc` crashes as soon as I try and run it. I've tried looking for some sort of configuration file where these values might be saved, but I can't find anything.

How do I reset `stereo_image_proc` to the default "safe" values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209039/how-to-reset-stereo_image_proc?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that you have a ros parameter that is set to a bad value.

You can list all of the parameters that are set using `rosparam list`

You can change the value of a parameter using `rosparam set /parameter value`

You can also clear all of your parameters by stopping your roscore and all of your nodes, and restarting them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1